# PHP undefined index

Tags: php

I am getting this error

[image]

and this is my php code:

```
<?php
    $host='localhost';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='';
    $db="dbmobile_class_record";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $stud_name=$_REQUEST['stud_name'];
    $score=$_REQUEST['score'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("UPDATE tb_quiz SET score = '$score' WHERE stud_name='$stud_name'",$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: @Uchiha uhmm actually it was based in a tutorial that i have been following and it did'nt have a form code :(

Comment: When you're setting your variables that should get some information from the server, the best practice is to use `isset` function combined with the check if your variable has something in it. Like: `$stud_name = (isset($_REQUEST['stud_name']) && $_REQUEST['stud_name'] != '') ? $_REQUEST['stud_name'] : '';`

Comment: Its because you were not getting the value within `$_REQUEST['stud_name']` you can check for `if(!empty($_REQUEST['stud_name'])){}` before your query

Comment: @dingo_d now it answers my question haha :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**`isset()` function**,](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check variable is **SET** (have some value ) or  **NULL**, as:

```
<?php
    $host='localhost';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='';
    $db="dbmobile_class_record";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    if( isset($_REQUEST['stud_name']) ){ $stud_name=$_REQUEST['stud_name']; } 
    else { $stud_name = ""; } // stud_name is empty

    if( isset($_REQUEST['score'])) { $score=$_REQUEST['score']; }
    else { $score= ""; } // score is empty

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("UPDATE tb_quiz SET score = '$score' WHERE stud_name='$stud_name'",$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I like ternary logic for variables more, kinda looks neater :)

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST['stud_name']` and `$_REQUEST['stud_name']` is not not defined / set.

Make sure the fields on your form have those name, you're requesting.

I would also recommend you to put a `isset` around the submit request variables, something like.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) 
{
     // Logic Here
     // Request variables
}
```

[Isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) manual here.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, check if the form is submitted or not. Otherwise it will insert empty rows.

Make sure your submit button has the name `submit`

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
```

Php code

```
<?php
    $host='localhost';
    $uname='root';
    $pwd='';
    $db="dbmobile_class_record";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        $stud_name=$_REQUEST['stud_name'] ? $_REQUEST['stud_name'] : "";
        $score=$_REQUEST['score'] ? $_REQUEST['score'] : "";

        $flag['code']=0;

        if($r=mysql_query("UPDATE tb_quiz SET score = '$score' WHERE stud_name='$stud_name'",$con))
        {
            $flag['code']=1;
        }

        print(json_encode($flag));
        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stud_name=$_REQUEST['stud_name'];
$score=$_REQUEST['score'];
```

IN above two line in place of stud_name write the name of field in that user enter student name and in place of score write na…e of the field in that user enter score of the student.

For ex. Your form contain two fields as below :

```
<input type='text' name='s_name'/>
<input type='text' name='s_score'/>
```

Then your line no 10 and 11 code must be like

```
 $stud_name=$_REQUEST['s_name'];
 $score=$_REQUEST['s_score'];
```

And this error also rise becouse form is not submited so `$_REQUEST['stud_name']` and `$_REQUEST['score']` is not set so you also first check value is set or not by `isset()` method like

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['s_name']) &&
    isset($_REQUEST['s_score']))
{
    $stud_name=$_REQUEST['s_name'];
    $score=$_REQUEST['s_score'];

}
```

Make suru your name of the fields and you put name in `$_REQUEST[""]` must be same name and your error goes.
Smile....